# Можно ли использовать программу с использованием openGL 1.0?

Tags: java, android, opengl

Изучаю книгу в которой для вывода графики автор использует openGL 1.0. Подскажите, будет ли программа, написанная с использованием openGL версии 1.0 работать на новых устройствах, которые уже поддерживают версию 3.0?

Comment: будет, но не тратьте время на опенгл1

Comment: Вы случайно не путаете OpenGL и OpenGL ES?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, я изучал openGL 2.0 по книге в которой описывается создание игры. Но в книге автор рассказывает как рисовать на экране точки, линии и треугольники. Как выводить на экран текстуры, к сожалению, он не рассматривает. Я нашёл другую книгу, в ней есть примеры использования текстур. Но она предназначена для openGL 1. Подскажите, где можно получить доступные (для новичка) сведения про openGL 2?

Comment: @andreymal, да я имел ввиду ES

Comment: Да, будет, у меня есть в магазине приложения написанные на OpenGL ES 1.0

Comment: @Style-7, можно ссылку? Хочется посмотреть как это выглядит

Comment: OpenGL версии 1 и 2 уже безнадежно устарел и не годится даже для учебных программ. OpenGL ES 1 тоже устарел в части fixed function pipeline, а OpenGL ES 2 еще более-менее живой. @Style-7 Вы видимо тоже путаете OpenGL ES и OpenGL.

Comment: @user7860670 уважаемый я не путаю и в ваших комментариях не нуждаюсь